# Mail using google apps rejected as SPAM, having trouble using SPF records

Tags: dns, google-workspace, mx

The situation:

- Domain name: fisharwe.com
- Site hosted by eukhost.com
- Domain name registrar: nearlyfreespeech.net
- Mx Records point to google apps servers
- created a TXT record at nearlyfreespeech with the following:

  - v=spf1 ip4:109.203.117.237 a:fisharwe.com include:aspmx.googlemail.com ~all
- Mail is sent either through the gapps web interface, either through the site (which uses ASP)
- Some mail still gets rejected as spam

I manage my own apache server, so I am not a complete newbie, but I am having trouble understanding DNSes. Specifically, I am not sure I really understand the syntax of SPF.
When I go to the [intodns check](http://www.intodns.com/fisharwe.com), I get a few errors still.
I don't really understand what to do. Google search yields a lot of resources, but most of them unclear, often contradicting each other. Is there any place that gives a comprehensive, cohesive view of how servers and DNS work? With a few receipes for most common use cases, that would be perfect.

For the record, here are the errors I get at intoDns:

- Domain NS records

  - Nameserver records returned by the parent servers are:

    - ns.phx3.nearlyfreespeech.net.   ['208.94.116.65']   [TTL=172800]
    - ns.phx7.nearlyfreespeech.net.   ['208.94.117.1']   [TTL=172800]
- NS records from your nameservers

  - NS records got from your nameservers listed at the parent NS are:

    - ns.phx3.nearlyfreespeech.net  ['208.94.116.65']   [TTL=3600]
    - ns.phx7.nearlyfreespeech.net  ['208.94.117.1']   [TTL=3600]
- Glue for NS records

  - INFO: GLUE was not sent when I asked your nameservers for your NS records.This is ok but you should know that in this case an extra A record lookup is required in order to get the IPs of your NS records. The nameservers without glue are:

    - 208.94.117.1
    - 208.94.116.65
  - You can fix this for example by adding A records to your nameservers for the zones listed above.
- SOA MNAME entry

  - WARNING: SOA MNAME (ns.phx1.nearlyfreespeech.net) is not listed as a primary nameserver at your parent nameserver!
  - Warn  SOA Serial  Your SOA serial number is: 1323999125. This can be ok if you know what you are doing.
  - Warn  SOA REFRESH     WARNING: Your SOA REFRESH interval is: 600. That is not so ok
- SOA EXPIRE

  - Your SOA EXPIRE number is: 86400. That is NOT OK
  - WWW A Record

    - Your www.fisharwe.com A record is:  [109.203.117.236]  [109.203.117.237]

I know this question is unlikely to serve the community as it is very specific, but I don't know where to turn to, I've been on this for days now. Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: found this http://rscott.org/dns/ which is a good resource

Answer (score 1):

Your SPF include for Google Apps is outdated.

Use the following:

```
include:_spf.google.com
```

Source: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60764

For reference, the record at _spf.google.com contains a significant range of Google IP addresses and should cover all cases where Google is sending mail:

```
_spf.google.com. 300 IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:216.239.32.0/19 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ip4:209.85.128.0/17 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:74.125.0.0/16 ip4:64.18.0.0/20 ip4:207.126.144.0/20 ip4:173.194.0.0/16 ?all"
```

Comment: and how would I also add the server which hosts the website? Or is it not needed? If it is, is this notation correct: [ v=spf1 ip4:109.203.117.237 a:fisharwe.com include:_spf.google.com ~all ]

Comment: That is valid (you can validate records here: http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html ). You only need to put IP addresses and A records for domains if they are used to send emails. If they are, then list them.